# Is there any general description language for block ciphers?

Tags: block-cipher, reference-request

In page 9 (16 in the PDF) of [Final report](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/Bookv015.pdf) of [European project IST-1999-12324 (NESSIE)](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/), it is mentioned that:

> The NESSIE project is also developing a new generic tool to analyze block
>   ciphers with differential [78] and linear cryptanalysis [422]. **This tool is based on
>   a general description language for block ciphers**.

- Is this "description language" publicly available?
- Is there any other general description language for block ciphers or stream ciphers?
- Is This tool publicly available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what is meant by this paragraph is the language defined in report NES/DOC/TEC/WP2/007/2, "[A System for Assisting Analysis of Some Block Ciphers](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/reports/phase2/definition.pdf)", by Arueh Bibliowicz, Pnina Cohen, Eli Biham. It is listed on the ["NESSIE public reports" page](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/reports/).

The language is something like a special-purpose programming language for block ciphers. It supports functions (with special notations for S-boxes and "Selections", rounds, key schedules), variables, constants, primitive arithmetic/binary operations (AND, OR, XOR, ADD, SUB, MULT, ROL, ROR, SHIFTL, SHIFTR).

The appendix contains DES as an example.

The `analyzer` tool mentioned there (which interprets the language and does some automated cryptanalysis) seems to be not public, though.