# Where can i find relative software for differential cryptanalysis?

Tags: cryptanalysis, linear-cryptanalysis

Is there any publicly known software for differential cryptanalysis over some cryptographic building blocks as blocks ciphers or cryptographic hash functions

Comment: see this question http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1012/132

Answer (score 4):

Not to my knowledge. Here is a possible explanation: non-trivial differential attacks are rather difficult to find in a fully automated way, and most of the time, one requires some (human) insight from a cryptanalyst before beginning to write some software.

Another explanation could be the following: cutting-edge differential attacks (like against SHA-3 candidates, for instance) are performed by world-class crypto researchers, and the competition (being the first to publish) is rather rough. So, people do not take the time, or are not always willing to share their software with everybody.